# Having a problem creating a multi-answer quiz in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my fixed indentation, pretty much I am trying to make a program where there is more than one 'answer' like a buzz-feed personality quiz. The program tries to guess where a person wants to go on vacation most. I have used a sort of template I found on youtube that works if there is only one 'right' answer, so I tried to use this except format it so each answer adds value and whattever letter has the most value will determine where the user should go on vacation.

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer
```

## Here is my edited code

```
from Question import Question

def main():
    print("Hello! This is a quiz that tries to guess where you want to go on vacation most based\n"\
          "on the answers you provide. Please respond with either 'a, b, c, or d.' Lets do this!\n")
    question_prompts = [
        "What is your go-to footwear?\n(a) Flip-flops\n(b) Sneaker\n(c) High-heels\n(d) Boots\n\n",
        "What is your favorite season?\n(a) Summer\n(b) Fall\n(c) Winter\n(d) Spring\n\n",
        "What is your favorite color?\n(a) Magenta\n(b) Teal\n(c) Yellow\n(d) Green\n\n",
        "What is your favorite fruit?\n(a) Watermelon\n(b) Pineapple\n(c) Mango\n(d) Peach\n\n",
        "What is your hair color?\n(a) Red\n(b) Blonde\n(c) Black\n(d) Brown\n\n",]
    questions = [
        Question(question_prompts[0]),
        Question(question_prompts[1]),
        Question(question_prompts[2]),
        Question(question_prompts[3]),
        Question(question_prompts[4])]
    test = run_test(questions)

def run_test(questions):
    score_one = 0
    score_two = 1
    score_three = 2
    score_four = 3
    score_five = 4

    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == 'a':
            score_one += 1
        elif answer == 'b':
            score_two += 1
        elif answer == 'c':
            score_three += 1
        elif answer == 'd':
            score_four += 1
        else:
            print('Invalid response')
            print(question_prompt)
    print("Result:", counter(answer)) 
run_test(questions)

#count total for each option
def counter(answer):
    if score_one > score_two and score_one > score_three and score_one > score_four:
        print('You should vacation at the beach!')
    elif score_two > score_one and score_two > score_three and score_two > score_four:
        print('You should vacation at the Swiss Alps!')
    elif score_three > score_one and score_three > score_two and score_three > score_four:
        print('You should vacation in Paris, France!')
    else: 
        print('You should go on vacation in Alaska!')

main()
```

Comment: You have indentation problems in your code. Was it just cut-and-paste errors or does your code really look like that? When you cut and paste code, first paste the whole thing, then select it all, and click the `{}` button to format the whole thing without risking corrupting it in the process.

Comment: Try building a tree, where each non leaf node is a question and the edges are possible answers. The leaf nodes are the guesses to where the user wants to vacation.

Comment: it might help if you can provide the trace back (the error that prints when you actually run the script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you haven't learned much about classes, you should understand the basics to see where you're going wrong.

Classes are a *blueprint* to create *objects* of a certain type. Objects are data structures that can be defined any way you want them to represent real-world objects. They hold data *fields*, whether they are `int`s, `str`s, etc., and they can have certain *behaviors* when you write *methods* in the class (methods are just functions that are defined in a class). When you create an object, like `q1 = Question('Enter a/b/c/d', 'b')`, the special `__init__` is called implicitly (automatically). The `self` parameter must be the first parameter in every method in a class. It is special in that you don't explicitely pass a value to it in parentheses when you create an object--the interpreter does this for you by sending in the reference name of the object itself as the first argument. So in this example, `self` is `q1`. The `__init__` method in your code would use this to set `q1.prompt = 'Enter a/b/c/d'` and `q1.answer = b`.

The first problem I see is that you are trying to create a `Question` object without giving it the arguments it needs to be created. You only pass it one argument, the prompt (I assume), but it needs two, both the prompt and the answer (remember that `self` is passed implicitly).

As others have mentioned, it would be helpful if you fix your indentation errors before we can help you further.

Comment: Thank you for this answer it is really helpful!!! I have fixed the indentation error I think, is there a way for me to use an input/output file and use the 'w' or 'a' operator instead of the class?

Comment: @slavel Yes, you can put each question on a separate line in a `file` and read them in to a list with `file.readlines()`. There is ample documentation on this site and elsewhere on getting input from files--start there if you need more info.